Coherent Noise channel options in stim?
What coherent noise channels can I apply on 2-qubit gates in stim? I believe that DEPOLARIZE is completely incoherent. I think I can use the PAULI_2 noise channel but I am not sure. Thanks a ton!

All noise in a stim Circuit is in the form of probabilistic Pauli gates. So it's incoherent (it looks like exponential decay, not like rotations, and there are no effects like constructive/destructive interference of noise).
Stim uses probabilistic Pauli because they are cheap to simulate, easy to analyze, and because quantum error correction digitizes coherent noise into Paulis anyways so they're a surprisingly good approximation.
The closest you can get to coherent noise is, when driving a tableau simulator with Python code, randomly apply a Clifford gate like an S gate.

Thanks, Craig, that makes sense. Just throwing my idea out here - would it also be equivalent to adding an S gate after each 2-qubit gate in the circuit to simulate the coherent error? I can just compile the circuit and run it the usual way after this.

@DHB that will give correct measurement results but all the qec features like detectors won't work because the analysis tools will assume the gates are intended and see that they make detectors non deterministic.
